# Yii operator '>=' requires two operands

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

I would like to delete records that have **level** same or greater than **$currentUserNC->level**, but I'm getting error: ***Operator '>=' requires two operands.*** 
Does anybody know how to resolve this? Thanks

```
NumbersCards::deleteAll(["AND", ["number" => $number->number], [">=", ["level" => $currentUserNC->level]]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper syntax is

```
[">=", "level", $currentUserNc->level]
```

Syntax

```
["level" => $currentUserNc->level]
```

is an alternative for

```
["=", "level", $currentUserNc->level]
```

Or for `IN` operator if the second operand is an array.